# Checking the proof for the following prime question.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Is my proof fully correct? I cannot see if I am missing anything critical so far.

Prove that for all natural numbers $p>2$, $p$ is prime if and only if for all natural numbers $a$ and $b$, if $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$.

Solution:
Since $p|ab$ there exists an integer $c$ such that $ab = pc.$
Since $p$ is prime, therefore, either $p|a$ or $(p,a)=1.$

If $p|a,$ we are done.

If $(p,a)=1$ then there exist an integer $s$ and $t$ such that $ps + at=1$
Now multiply with $b$ on both sides

$$
psb +(ab)t = b
$$

Put $ab=pc$ 
$\longrightarrow$ $p(sb+tc)=b$
Therefore, $p|b.$

Comment: Looks fine to me. And it works for $p=2$ too.

Comment: @learner thank you!

Comment: For the record, this is called Euclid's lemma and your proof is given in the first section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma#Proof). There's another proof of it there in case you're interested.

Comment: @learner yea I stated Euclid's lemma but I guess it was assumed we would use it so I didn't have to. Also, can I get your input on this on please? I just want to know if its sufficient enough to receive full marks. Thank you again. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138859/checking-proof-for-the-following-gcd-question

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the "if and only if": you need to prove the converse too. Here's a hint: suppose $p$ is not prime, so there's $1\lt c\lt p$ such that $c\mid p$. Now, let $a=c,b=p/c$, so $p\mid ab=p$ which implies $p\mid c$ or $p\mid p/c$. Can you see the contradiction?

Comment: each possibility is impossible therefore contradiction? @learner

Comment: Yes, but you need to elaborate on how each of the two possibilities are impossible.

Comment: If p is composite, meaning it is not prime and has no other divisors aside from 1 and $a$, we can write $p=ab$ with $1<a,b<p.$ However, $p|ab,$ so if we assume the condition of the theorem from before, either $p|a$ or $p|b.$  @learner

Comment: Hmm, that works too.

Answer (score 1):

The proposition is a biimplication. You have proved that if $p$ is prime, then whenever $p | ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$. You must also prove the converse, namely that if whenever $p | ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$, then $p$ is prime.